# Silverlight object seems to be auto-reloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have a rather complex web page structure containing a Silverlight control. The control loads and functions fine. However, sometimes the control seems to auto-reload itself. I'm not sure how, or why - and I'm fairly sure there's no external code in the web page that's causing it.

Basically, the way I noticed this is that the control contains some cached data. When it's created, the data is passed from JavaScript to the Silverlight control, which is then cached. The data is then deleted from the JavaScript side. Almost randomly, the Silverlight control throws an error saying there is no cached data. I found that this is because the control is re-loaded somehow - though not by JavaScript as the relevant area within JavaScript where the SL control is created is never hit a second time. But the Application_Startup event handler within the SL control is hit a second time.

Unfortunately, I cannot post the code as it is commercial and I have not yet managed to recreate this issue in a test project. I will post code if/when I do.

If that makes any sense, does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on the matter?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. I've been having problems with running the Silverlight plugin in both Chrome and Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see plugins auto reload when specific DOM elements change.  Are you manipulating the DOM somehow?

Here's an example of it happening in Flash, though I've ran into the same issue with Silverlight.  This is more of a Browser issue and not specific to Silverlight or Flash.

[Stop reloading flash file when using show and hide methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587087/stop-reloading-flash-file-when-using-show-and-hide-methods)

Comment: Many thanks. That makes sense and turned out to be the root cause of my issue.